# Create a new variable in a dataframe based on an existing variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using a dataframe, I am trying to create a new string variable called CLASS based on RISK_RATING values. If the RISK_RATING values contain ‘PEP’, ‘PEP’ will be the CLASS value. Otherwise, ‘SF’ will be the CLASS name. If there is no RISK_RATING value, the CLASS name is to be 'missing'

```
Here is a sample of my dataframe:
    BUSINESS    CUSTOMER_ID   RISK_RATING
0   PVB          1000033280     HR
1   PVB          1000166304     PEP (SR)
2   PVB          1004006928     PEP (SR)
3   PVB          1004006936     PEP (SR)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified it as much as possible, try the below:

```
import numpy as np
df['CLASS'] = np.where(df['RISK_RATING'].str.contains('PEP'),'PEP','SF')
df['CLASS'] = np.where(df['RISK_RATING'].isnull(),'missing',df['CLASS'])
```

Will get you:

```
  BUSINESS  CUSTOMER_ID RISK_RATING CLASS
0      PVB   1000033280          HR    SF
1      PVB   1000166304    PEP (SR)   PEP
2      PVB   1004006928    PEP (SR)   PEP
3      PVB   1004006936    PEP (SR)   PEP
```

Comment: By the way, I corrected something that was missing from my code. Try it again if you want please.

Comment: no problem buddy, that's completely fine. Everyone was new at some point. Try the code again and let me know if it gives you an error again. We will fix it

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid that this is still not working, I am receiving an error: "ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given"

Comment: This is strange then. I will need to see your dataset. Is there a chance you can post  a sample of it in your question?

Comment: Thanks - I have added to the question :)

Comment: It seems to be working on mine, I posted the result in my answer.

Comment: you are an absolute superstar. Thank you so much, it's working. My very first question has been a pleasure on Stack Overflow. Have a class day wherever you are!

Answer (score 0):

you need to initiate the column `CLASS`
`df['CLASS'] = "SF"`

use `.loc` to assign a new value to the column

`df.loc[df['RISK_RATING'].str.contains("PEP"), 'CLASS'] = 'PEP'`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm afraid your solution is providing me with the error message: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'. In your solution, what is the purpose of assigning all values in 'CLASS' with "N"? I have updated my question with a sample of my dataframe

Comment: Well, I forgot a bracket at the end of `df['RISK_RATING']` that's why you got the error, the purpose for me is not to provide you with an answer that you copy/paste and voilà it works, but give you enough information to get you to achieve your goal. For the "N" it's the default value for your column, I've updated my answer since you updated your question for the default value to be "SF".
I don't see why my answer was downvoted though